# how to Curl comment to jersey client

Tags: java, curl, jersey, jersey-client

How to add bellow curl comment to the jersey client.

```
curl -X POST --user 'gigy:secret' -d 'grant_type=password&username=peter@example.com&password=password' http://localhost:8000/gigy/oauth/token
```

I tried to like bellow. but I don't know how to add other things.

```
Client client = Client.create();
WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://localhost:8000/gigy/oauth/token");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `--user 'gigy:secret'`

You need [Basic Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). Basically You need to set the `Authorization` header with the value `Basic base64("gigy:secret")`, where `base64` is whatever you use to convert the string `"user:password"` to its Base 64 counterpart. You can set headers on the `WebResource` calling one it's `header` method.

> `-d 'grant_type=password&username=peter@example.com&password=password'`

These are `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` parameters. This is what you will need to send as the entity body of the request. With Jersey you can use the [`com.sun.jersey.api.representation.Form`](http://javadox.com/com.sun.jersey/jersey-core/1.19/com/sun/jersey/api/representation/Form.html) class. Once you create it, just add key value/pairs to it like key=grant_type and value=password. All the pairs split by `&`.

> Implicit Media type.

When you don't set the `Content-Type` header in your cURL request, a POST will default to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. You need to set this using the `type(MediaType)` function after you call `header`. Use `MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE`.

> `-X POST`

Now you need to send the request. Just call `post` after you call `type`, with the following arguments `.post(ClientResponse.class, yourForm)`. This will return a `ClientResponse`.